# Ellipsis in flutter not working as Expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

**Below is the sample code, I am not able to see ellipsis at the end when the text reaches the maximum available space. it limit the the text length to one line. I need the text to take the full available space and at the end it should show ellipsis without cropping. Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class Single extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _SingleState createState() => _SingleState();
    }

   class _SingleState extends State<Single> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Material(
          child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "test",
          ),
          Container(
              height: 80,
              child: new Text('Title',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual wordSometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference: order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference: Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              softWrap: true,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 52,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "12 comments",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(65, 64, 64, 1),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "22 likes",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(65, 64, 64, 1),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        size: 24.0,
                        semanticLabel:
                            'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.audiotrack,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        size: 24.0,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.beach_access,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        size: 24.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Got that fixed ? @tinto

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

This is no easy feat. We must assign a `GlobalKey` to the `Expanded` widget wrapping the `Text` widget so that we can determine its height *after* it is drawn. Then we must update the `maxLines` property and rebuild. Calculating the number of lines by dividing the widget height by the font size.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class Single extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SingleState createState() => _SingleState();
}

class _SingleState extends State<Single> {
  final _key = GlobalKey();
  int numLines = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        numLines = _key.currentContext.size.height ~/
            (Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.fontSize + 3);
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Material(
          child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "test",
          ),
          Container(
              height: 80,
              child: new Text('Title',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
          Expanded(
            key: _key,
            child: Text(
              'Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual wordSometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference: order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference: Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:Sometimes an article modifies a noun that is also modified by an adjective. The usual word order is article + adjective + noun. If the article is indefinite, choose a or an based on the word that immediately follows it. Consider the following examples for reference:',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              softWrap: true,
              maxLines: numLines,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 52,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "12 comments",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(65, 64, 64, 1),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "22 likes",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(65, 64, 64, 1),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        size: 24.0,
                        semanticLabel:
                            'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.audiotrack,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        size: 24.0,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.beach_access,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        size: 24.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to use the full available space. So max lines is not a good idea. I have tried that too won't work as expected. You can just run and see.

Comment: That is the only way that you are extending a `Text` widget beyond 1 line. Why not calculate and set the maxLines based on the detected available space?

Comment: can I get any sample for this approach?

Comment: this approach won't take all the available space. please cross check. I have tested

Comment: Okay. I think the latest update will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of what this did vs. what you are expecting.

Comment: like ragu said below it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is not possible for the `Text` widget to occupy the entire space in the column and also to support the ellipsis. Because, `ellipsis` property will be logically working based on the lines that needs to be displayed. This tells the widget, where exactly the `ellipsis` property should apply.

> Like, when `maxLines` is 1, then property will be applied at the end
> of first line, or  when `maxLines` is 5, then `ellipsis` will be
> applied at the end of the 5th line and so on.

If you want the `Text` widget to occupy the entire space(in Question, remaining space) in the `Column`, `overflow` property should be removed. **In this case, you will not have `ellipsis` property and some of the text will be invisible to user**.

So in above approach, you can wrap `Text` inside the `SingleChildScrollView` to make your text scrollable and can occupy the entire space. But if the text is short, there can be some empty space between.

If you literally wants the `ellipsis` property, then go for the `maxLines` field as mentioned by @Lee3.

This is how the snippet will look,

```
Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Text(
        ' <-- Your Long Text here -->',
        softWrap: true,
      ),
    )),
```

Let me know for any queries. .